# Scrape all matching contents using XPath function

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

How do I make sure that my selenium code scrapes all matching contents of my XPath?
Please help me with your ideas.

For example, these are my HTML Tags:

```
<tr class="1" role="r1">
    <td class="c1">
        <a href="www.google.com">
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="2" role="r2">
    <td class="c2">
        <a href="www.youtube.com">
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="3" role="c3">
    <td class="c3">
        <a href="www.facebook.com">
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want my selenium code to fetch all links from href tag.
So, below is my XPath:

```
String links = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@role='cad']//td[@class='c1']//a")).getAttribute("href"); 
System.out.println(links);
```

but it fetches only the first href output, i.e. `www.google.com`.

The desired output is:

```
www.google.com
www.youtube.com
www.facebook.com
```

How can I achieve this?
Any array implementation would be better options?

Comment: You need to first store all elements of <table> tag and then identify all the <a> tags by checking 'href' attribute

Comment: Did you try `driver.findElements()`? Note the extra "s" for plural elements.

Comment: @SiKing: You mean like this? `String links =((WebElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@role='cad']//td[@class='c1']//a"))).getAttribute("href")` It din work ... Any suggestions?? `string` datatype is mismatching?

Comment: Hi @kushalツ - Can you please eloborate with ex, if possible? Not clear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Following code:

```
 List<WebElement> elements= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr"));

    int i =0 ;

    while(i<elements.size()){

        WebElement childElement =  elements.get(i).findElement(By.cssSelector("a"));

    System.out.println(childElement.getAttribute("href"));

    i++;
    }
```

Comment: Beautiful; it is working.. Still I am wondering, this is the most effective solution... Thanks ANyways.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr/td/a"));

    for(int i=0;i<links.size();i++){
        System.out.println(links.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
    }
```

Comment: Did you get a chance to try this solution?